# Angular.js - not enter inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iife

Why not enter in `AddTaskComponentController` and display my `console.log('TESTE456214651')`? The code is in the same archive, because I'm using grunt.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('dailyTasksApp', []).config(config)

    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'modules/construction-employees-daily-tasks/app/app.component.html'
        }).when('/adicionar-tarefa', {
            templateUrl: 'modules/construction-employees-daily-tasks/add-task-component/add-task.component.html'
        })
    }
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('dailyTasksApp').component('addTaskComponent', {
        templateUrl: '/modules/construction-employees-daily-tasks/add-task-component/add-task.component.html',
        controller: AddTaskComponentController
    })

    function AddTaskComponentController() {
        console.log("TESTE456214651");
    }
})();
```

Comment: You never call the function. It's only declared.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your function as an Angular controller.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('dailyTasksApp', [])
        .config(config)

    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'modules/construction-employees-daily-tasks/app/app.component.html'
            })
            .when('/adicionar-tarefa', {
                templateUrl: 'modules/construction-employees-daily-tasks/add-task-component/add-task.component.html'
            })
    }
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('dailyTasksApp')
        .controller('AddTaskComponentController',
           function(){
               console.log("TESTE456214651");
           })
        .component('addTaskComponent', {
            templateUrl: '/modules/construction-employees-daily-tasks/add-task-component/add-task.component.html',
            controller: AddTaskComponentController
        })

})();
```